# Replace the header of a file with another one

Tags: bash

I want to replace the header of a file in hex (512 first bytes) by another one from a file and add a tail from another file. I'm a noob but I know how to cut the header with `xxd` and I know how to concatenate text with `cat` but I don't understand how to make the two commands work together.

```
cat new_head xxd -s 512 file_to_modify cat new_tail > new_file
```

I know the code is silly but I've tried several other things and this one is probably easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping):

```
{ cat 'new_head'; tail -c +513 'file_to_modify'; cat 'new_tail'; } > 'new_file'
```

Or [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution):

```
cat 'new_head' <(tail -c +513 'file_to_modify') 'new_tail' > 'new_file'
```